# Override property in Swift 3

Tags: swift, inheritance, getter-setter

I want to override properties in the following class. Say I have a class `A` that has a boolean property `r`. For the superclass `A`, I want `r` to be set and get normally. For the subclass `B`, I want `r` to always be `false`. I'm not sure why this is harder than it should be...

```
class A {
    init(r: Bool) {
        self.r = r
    }

    var r: Bool {
        willSet(n) {
            r = n
        }
        get {
            return r
        }
    }
}

class B: A {
    override var r: Bool {
        willSet(n) {
            r = n
        }
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
}

let a = A(r: true)
a.r = false
print(a.r)  // prints 'false', which is good

let b = B(r: true)
print(b.r)  // prints 'true'
b.r = false // ERROR: I can't get pass this point 'Execution was interrupted on playground
print(b.r)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile – you cannot use a property observer (`willSet`) with a computed property. And even if it did compile, `get { return r }` would cause a recursive loop, and the `willSet` implementations don't do anything. You probably want just a stored property in the base class, with a computed property override in the subclass.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use the stored property and override with computed in the subclass? I want `r` to always be `false` in the subclass.

Comment: Did you check the similar question in the "Related" section?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Hamish: stored property in base class, with computed property override. Except, a read-only property can't override a mutable property. But, you can make the overridden setter do nothing, and the overridden getter return what you want.

```
class A {
    init(r: Bool) {
        self.r = r
    }

    var r: Bool
}

class B: A {
    override var r: Bool {
        set {}
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
}

let a = A(r: true)
print(a.r) // "true"
a.r = false
print(a.r) // "false"

let b = B(r: true)
print(b.r) // "false"
b.r = true
print(b.r) // "false"
```